# how to get graphics card memory info? windows and linux shows different value

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, ram

In my Windows 8, video card shows 640 MB of available memory (Screen Resolution > Advanced Settings or with dxdiag). But ubuntu (with lspci command) shows 256 MB. so who's right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check video memory size?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46197/how-to-check-video-memory-size)

Answer (score 11):

1- install sysinfo :

```
sudo apt-get install sysinfo
```

and then run it -->

```
sysinfo
```

2- Alternatively use :

```
sudo lshw -businfo | grep -i display
```

find your exact graphic card model and check the manufacturer website

3- there are other command as well like :

```
sudo apt-get install hardinfo
```

[image]

Hope that works ;)

Comment: hardinfo is incapable of showing GPU VRAM. Where on your screenshot is total amount of VRAM displayed??

Comment: None of the mentioned tools shows amount of VRAM on Asus G551JM notebook with GeForce GTX 860M.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1.
`lspci | grep VGA` 
Note down the numbers at the beginning of the output line. E.g 00:02.0

Just for information: this number provides the domain, bus, slot and function parameter for your graphics card `[[[[<domain>]:]<bus>]:][<slot>][.[<func>]]`

Step 2.
Insert the above number after -s parameter
So if the number was 00:02.0 then the command will be
 `lspci -v -s 00:02.0`

Answer (score 1):

The following steps worked for me:- (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

1. Use command `lspci | grep VGA` to find graphics card. You will get something like this `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)`.
2. Kindly focus on the `00:02.0` part, it might be different for you. Then use this command `lspci -v -s 00:02.0`. Use your own pattern in place of mine.
3. Then you will get all information related to that graphics card like this [My Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaIgH.png)

Hope this helps. If helps then upvote please so that i can give more answers and interact more in the community.