# Lubuntu 20.04 not detecting my ram

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, ram

I had 4gb ram on a old desktop pc, I just installed 4gb extra ram. Bios detects 8gb, windows detects it. But linux only sees 4gb.

uname -a:

```
Linux appie-imedia-S2185 5.4.0-70-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 13:29:52 UTC 2021 x86_64  
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

free -m:

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3365        1278         806         100        1280        1753
Swap:          3514           0        3514
```

cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i memtotal

```
MemTotal:        3446176 kB
```

But then lshw notices there is actually 8gb:

lshw -short | grep 'System\ Memory':

```
/0/14                        memory         8GiB System Memory
```

Since Bios, Windows and lshw sees the 8gb, the problem should be with linux.... Anyone any clue on how to make linux see and use all my ram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `free` shows is what is available for the OS to use.
As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130626/226614), the difference might have been taken by the graphics.

OTOH, `lshw` shows the amount of hardware RAM, which is what you see in the BIOS/Windows (which would likely also use some of the 8Gb for shared video RAM).

Note that some commands may help assessing the difference:

1. `lshw -class memory -short` (a slight modification of your command).
2. `free -h` (a slight modification of your command).
3. `sudo dmidecode | less` (showing info on the physical memory banks, etc.) You may add option `--type memory`.
4. `htop`
5. Comment #10 in [this thread](https://itsfoss.community/t/ram-in-lshw-compared-to-free/3368).
6. `cat /var/log/kern.log | grep -i memory`
7. `cat /var/log/kern.log.1 | grep -i memory` (and possibly other gzipped logs, [ref](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181067/how-to-read-dmesg-from-previous-session-dmesg-0))

**Related**:

1. https://itsfoss.community/t/ram-in-lshw-compared-to-free/3368
2. https://linuxhint.com/commands-to-manage-linux-memory/
3. [How to find how much RAM does my computer have?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302586/how-to-find-how-much-ram-does-my-computer-have)
4. [how to get graphics card memory info? windows and linux shows different value](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304566/how-to-get-graphics-card-memory-info-windows-and-linux-shows-different-value)

Comment: Hmmm, i removed the ram and put it back in several times. And now all sudenly htop shows 7.2 gb...

Comment: @Arjan - I don't know what else changed in your case, and whether you found out more information about the suggested cause of the difference. Please see also added link #4.