# RAM usage by integrated graphics

Tags: ram, amd-graphics, thinkpad

I have a ThinkpadP14s gen2 with AMD Ryzen 7 pro 5850u with radeon graphics × 16, 16GB RAM and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. System monitor detects only 12.4GB of RAM, so i thought it's because of integrated graphics, but in my BIOS i can't see the video option, can anyone help me?

Comment: See what video option?

Comment: I think he/she will know if is a way to find out how many ram is for an integrated grafikcard is reserverd.

Comment: Have you tried [the commands in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/475405/1222991) to see how much memory might be allocated to the graphics subsystem? 

Comment: Options to edit pre allocated RAM for Graphics, i saw it in some tutorials for other PCs. I tried those commands and it says 256MB which looks strange.